# ¿Cómo puedo pasar una imagen que contenga texto a texto en android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Lo que quiero implementar es que cuando se apriete un botón te direccione a la cámara y se pueda tomar o elegir una foto y después el texto de la imagen se pueda transcribir a un `EditText`, espero me puedan ayudar.

Este es mi codigo en android studio

```
package e.macg.traductorbeta;

import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextToSpeech mTTS;
    private EditText mEditText;
    private SeekBar mSeekBarPitch;
    private SeekBar mSeekBarSpeed;
    private Button mButtonSpeak;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mButtonSpeak = findViewById(R.id.button_speak);

        mTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
                    int result = mTTS.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());

                    if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED){
                        Log.e("TTS","LENGUAJE NO SOPORTADO");
                    }else {
                        mButtonSpeak.setEnabled(true);
                        speak();
                    }
                }else{
                    Log.e("TTS","INIALIZACION FALLIDA");
                }
            }
        });

        mEditText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        mSeekBarPitch = findViewById(R.id.seek_bar_pitch);
        mSeekBarSpeed = findViewById(R.id.seek_bar_speed);

        mButtonSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                speak();
            }
        });

    }
    private void speak(){
        String text = mEditText.getText().toString();
        float pitch = (float) mSeekBarPitch.getProgress() / 50;
        if (pitch < 0.1) pitch =0.1f;
        float speed = (float) mSeekBarSpeed.getProgress() / 50;
        if (speed < 0.1) speed =0.1f;

        mTTS.setPitch(pitch);
        mTTS.setSpeechRate(speed);

        mTTS.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if(mTTS != null){
            mTTS.stop();
            mTTS.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: lo que necesitas implementar es el uso de un API o Servicio de OCR (Optical Character Recognition ), esto no es parte de los API's estandar de Android por tanto es muy probable cualquier respuesta se base en opinion.

Comment: Para implementar OCR (Optical Character Recognition) en tu applicacion debes utilizar un API(fuera del Core de Android)(o crear tu propio sistema de OCR).

Realizando una investigacion Rapida en Google. note que la Opcion mas utilizada es [FireBase](https://firebase.google.com) (una plataforma de desarrollo. otra opcion es el ["obsoleto" Vision](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mobile-vision-ocr/)
el reconocimiento de texto y segun se expone en la pagina de [FireBase TextRecognition](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/recognize-text)

Comment: puedes bajar [el codigo de Ejemplo](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/mlkit) o [realizar un laboratorio](http://g.co/codelabs/mlkit-android) que explica el uso de esta plataforma para reconocimiento de texto.

Comment: OCR (Optical Character Recognition ), revisa si OpenCV sirve para android.